# Check if Div which has both "unique class and Id" exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, video-player, jwplayer6

I am using some HTML5 video player `JWPLAYER` which adds certain class like `JWPLAYER` to its video_container dynamically.

Now when close button clicked I am hiding or removing the player, Problem I faced was sometime user may try to click close button before the video or `JWPLAYER` is loaded fully, which causes unwanted error or sometimes div is hidden but video sound is being played in background.

Since I have unique ID for each div and `jwplayer` class is added dynamically.I am wondering if it possible to check if div exist which has both `uniqueId and class`

```
<div class = 'myclasss' id = 'myid'> </div>
```

I may have multiple player in DOM, so I need to have unique Id with class to check if DIV exist.
I know it is possible to check this with separate class or id , As described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-exists-in-jquery/) but can it be checked with both ID and CLASS.

I understand My Approach might be wrong, if you have better solution please do tell, But being a new learner, just out of curiosity I have asked this dummy question (if some may feel so).

Kindly help me find the answer

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Do you want to know if you can check there's only 1 element with a certain `id` and `class` or do you want to check if an element with a certain `id` has a certain `class`?

Comment: Why in first place are you using IDs? Anyway, i'm not sure to understand your issue: `if div exist which has both uniqueId and class` ???

Comment: @LuudJacobs : Sorry, if I have not asked clearly, My apology for bad english.  `I want to know if element with a certain id and class exist` so i would go with second one `To check if an element with a certain id has a certain class`

Comment: @A.Wolff : I am setting the div ID but class is added dynamically to that div after third party videoPlayer JS is fully loaded. I hope I am making some sense :( ... sorry for confusion.

Comment: Is my question really unclear ? Can someone help me write it better ?`Thanks`

Comment: @hitesh `To check if an element with a certain id has a certain class` then go with `hasClass()` or you could use `$('#myID.myClass').length`. Both answers below are correct

Comment: Thanks you are right !!! Just now I checked ...

Comment: Both answers below work for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use a special selector, like this:

```
$('#myID.myClass')
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vqwxc/

Answer (score 6):

You can use **[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)**:

```
if($('#myid').hasClass('myclass')) {
    // Your code here
}
```